# toggle list, hide the other when open one

Tags: jquery

I have a list with several elements that I open when clicking. currently allows all open at the same time. but I want that always leaves open only one element. if one is open and I click it to another before the close.

```
$('#karriere .vacancy-item .box-title__red').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('vacancy-active');
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
```

Comment: Add the HTML as well.

Comment: Sounds like a standard jQuery accordion.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/WMUJ3/317/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/s9dmR/12/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/WvtEw/298/

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7TEsP/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("li").click(function(){

 $(this).nextAll() .toggle();
 $(this).prevAll().toggle();

});

});
</script>

<ul>
    <li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>
```